# Swiffy on Android browser

Tags: flash, html, google-swiffy

I would like to use Swiffy to convert Flash animations to HTML5. 
The converted HTML5 output run on modern browsers and iOS device, but doesn't work on Android(below 4).

You can test http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/gallery.html on Android.

Android browsers supports Canvas and SVG. Then, does anybody know what lacks in Android browser to show the Swiffy output? If I know it, I will try to change Swiffy JavaScript.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the older android browsers supports SVG, but not inline SVG. Only android 3 and up supports it..
[Inline SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline%20svg)