# Exporting Flash to HTML5, compatible with Android2.3

Tags: android, flash, html, html5-animation

I would like to create animations compatible with Android2.3, using Adobe Flash Pro CS6.
Since I don't want to be dependent on Flash Player on the device, I would like to save the animation as HTML5.

So far, I used [Swiffy](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) to convert the swf output to HTML5 but it doesn't run on Android 2.3 device, only on Android 3 and up.
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289233/swiffy-on-android-browser) that the reason might be that "older android browsers supports SVG, but not [inline SVG](http://caniuse.com/#search=inline%20svg). Only android 3 and up supports it."

I am an Android developer and not familiar with Adobe Flash Pro, but I would like to instruct my graphic designer how to create the animations or what settings to use when he creates the swf/html5 files so that they would run on Android 2.3.

Can anyone help or give me some guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Adobe Edge](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/) ?

Taken right from the description

> "Adobe® Edge is a powerful, intuitive tool for creating stunning
>   animated and interactive content using HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript."

Note that Adobe Edge is still in beta. Give it a try and see whether you will be able to leverage your existing skills in Flash.